# Store and recall button in calculator application (iPhone)

Tags: iphone

I'm new in iPhone development. I made a calculator in which I need to put 2 more buttons:

1. `Store`: Stores the current value of the display into a memory location.
2. `Recall`: Recalls the value in memory.

But I don't know how.

Comment: How do you store the current number so that you can perform operations on it?  That might give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, but how did you make a calculator app if you don't know how to store a value somewhere and retrieve it when needed?

Anyway, just use a variable.